# Web Scraping a page that needs a while to load with R, rvest, Rslenium

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I am trying to web scrape the page https://sibdatabase.socialfinance.org.uk/ and get the elements from the class="list".

The issue is that when I try to use rvest the page is not loaded yet:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://sibdatabase.socialfinance.org.uk/"

url %>%
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes(".list")
```

And the output is

```
{xml_nodeset (0)}
```

I also tried RSelenium, but an error is occurring:

```
library(RSelenium)

driver <- rsDriver()
remDr <- driver[["client"]]
remDr$navigate("https://sibdatabase.socialfinance.org.uk/")

Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
     Summary: SessionNotCreatedException
     Detail: A new session could not be created.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
Check server log for further details.
```

Comment: Do you have Firefox installed? If so, try with `rsDriver(browser="firefox")` instead of Chrome. I also have some issues with RSelenium and Chrome now (RSelenium seems to be waiting for Chrome version 90, which isn't released yet - but I might be mistaken).

Comment: Also didn't work:  (os error 10061)
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-2', revision: 'f148142cf8', time: '2019-07-01T21:30:10'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-QA3FFFR7', ip: '172.19.59.4', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_211'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: 

Could not open firefox browser.
Client error message:
  Summary: Timeout
   Detail: An operation did not complete before its timeout expired.
  Further Details: run errorDetails method
Check server log for further details.

Comment: Strange.. I tried using `webdriver` package, discovered that it opens well without trouble, but then again discovered that the page opens without any trouble using `RSelenium` with `rsDriver(browser="firefox")` from my end.

Comment: Yep, I checked on another computer with Firefox now, and it worked well. I could also get an output with `html_nodes(".list")`. I sense that there is something wrong with RSelenium's current compatibility with some browsers (especially Chrome), see here: https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/245

Comment: What you want to extract from the website?